# Firebase Realtime Database doesn't retrieve into my app listview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android app that retrieves data from a Firebase realtime database, and I completed all the steps of the implementation and the configuration of the server connection but when I run my app in Android studio I do not get any result.

This is the debugging "logcat" message

> *V/FA : Inactivity disconnected from the service*
>   *F/FirebaseInctanceId: Token Retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILBLE*

I tried to uninstall Android app from my phone and chose to invalidate Cache/ Restart in Android studio but no result.

How can I resolve this problem,  please?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your google services.json for your app Id and use those ones. The .json file you download while initializing your app from the firebase website

Comment: i did it but no result even i have been created a new project but same negative result